# Font size issue and screen tearing on Arch with Nvidia

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, nvidia, fontconfig

I have followed instructions on how to setup [font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration) as well as [Nvidia drivers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Driver_installation) and [their configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Automatic_configuration).

What is causing very small fonts in most of my applications?

---

Below are the specifics on how I configured my system. No desktop environment, only Xorg + [EXWM](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm).

```
❯ neofetch --off 

OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Kernel: 5.9.14-arch1-1 
Uptime: 14 hours, 55 mins 
Packages: 532 (pacman) 
Shell: zsh 5.8 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
WM: EXWM 
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: emacs 
CPU: Intel i5-6500 (4) @ 3.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB 
Memory: 3509MiB / 7879MiB
```

#### Nvidia

```
❯ grep "X Driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log

[  1549.777] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  455.45.01  Thu Nov  5 23:01:05 UTC 2020
```

I tried the following command which seemed to help with screen tearing:

```bsh
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

as per [this section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing) of the Nvidia troubleshooting Wiki page, but having no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` I'm not sure what went wrong during my installation. According to the `man` pages, I might also need to set `$XORGCONFIG` so that this specific folder is taken into account.

```
❯ ll /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d 

total 12K
-rw-r--r-- 1  227 Nov 21 20:05 10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.4K Dec 14 13:10 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.4K May 19  2020 40-libinput.conf
```

```
❯ ll /etc/X11/ 

total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 4.0K Dec 19 01:18 xinit
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.8K Dec 24 11:07 xorg.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 1.7K Dec 24 11:07 xorg.conf.backup
-rw-r--r-- 1    0 Dec 20 17:14 xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original
```

#### Xorg

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

https://bpa.st/VXAQ . Which for some reason doesn't show about the second monitor.

`~/.xinitrc`

```bsh
picom &                                 # Compositor
sh ~/.config/emacs/exwm/start.sh        # Start Emacs window manager
```

`start.sh`

https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/exwm/start.sh

#### Fonts

```
❯ inxi -G            

Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] driver: nvidia v: 455.45.01 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.10 driver: nvidia resolution: 1: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           2: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 455.45.01
```

In addition to the instructions found in the font configuration Wiki page, I recorded some of the extra configuration I did here: https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/DESKTOP.org#fonts .

With regards to very small font size and *ugliness* -- unable to find a better term describing it and it doesn't exactly show with screenshots -- it's a little better in some places when I increase the DPI through my Xresources https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/exwm/xresources but while it does make it less bad in places where font were too small, it also make them too big in places where they were fine initially ie. percent-based sizes like `em` in Web pages. I left it at `120` for now but I suspect it should be `101` in my case:

```
❯ xdpyinfo | grep dots 

  resolution:    101x101 dots per inch
```

Also maybe relevant, I used to use the `Monaco` font on a MacBook Pro with latest macOS where the font looked thicker and had *better* rounding on the edges. Using `ttf-monaco` on Arch shows thin and less smooth edges and solutions found with regards to "hinting" didn't work for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you please post each of these three questions separately? As it stands, this is asking 3 questions in one which is too broad for the Stack Exchange format. When asking about the screen tearing, please include the output of `inxi -G`. When asking about fonts, make sure to tell us what desktop manager you are using or, if none, mention that you don't have a GUI.

Comment: Hello! I was thinking that my 3 questions were in fact 3 symptoms of one issue in my configuration so I should have worded that better probably. I'll edit in output for `inxi` thanks

Comment: @terdon Edited to be more clear about what the actual question is, also added `inxi` output. Thanks for the feedback, do let me know if/how I can make it easier still.